How to syncronize `tensorflow-intel` , `grpcio-tools`, `googleapis-common-protos` and `protobuf` library
I have a dependency conflict because tensorflow-intel and grpcio-tools have incompatible version requirements for the protobuf library. Here;s the condition:

tensorflow-intel 2.17.0 requires protobuf version to be >=3.20.3 but not in the range 4.21.0 through 4.21.5 and less than 5.0.0dev.
grpcio-tools 1.63.0 requires protobuf to be >=5.26.1 and less than 6.0dev.
googleapis-common-protos 1.63.2 depends on protobuf!=3.20.0, !=3.20.1, !=4.21.1, !=4.21.2, !=4.21.3, !=4.21.4, !=4.21.5, <6.0.0.dev0 and >=3.20.2

These constraints cannot be satisfied simultaneously because tensorflow-intel does not support protobuf versions that grpcio-tools requires, and vice versa.
How to find compatible versions to update requirements.txt accordingly?
